# Automatically fill in attributes of parent feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, geopackage, relation

I have a data table that holds different information about buildings in a GeoPackage. Different elements of the buildings can be entered, e.g. sometimes I only have the building as a whole, sometimes I have an entry for each room. Each entry has a `"UUID"` as a unique key. I use QGIS 3.16.3.

A simplified version of the table looks like this:
[image]

You can download the simplified sample data [here](https://we.tl/t-xnrM1NyJo5).

I added a field `"uuid_parent"` and created a recursive relation, which works fine, e.g. I can link a room to the building the room is in via the buildings `"UUID"`. Now I would like to fill in all the information that necessarily are identical with the parent automatically, e.g. the address or the postal code.

The relation is defined like this:

[image]

I tried using a `relation_aggregate()` function as the field default in the layer properties on the field *address* like this:

```
relation_aggregate(
    relation:='entities_d_uuid_parent_entities_d_uuid',
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:="address"
    )
```

Unfortunately I only get `NULL`-Values so far. I created a small sample data set, that shows, how it is supposed to look in the end. In this case, I had to type in the entries in the field `"address"` by hand, however:

[image]

Edit after hints by @pigreco and @Babel:

I edited the default expression into the following:

```
array_to_string(
    relation_aggregate(
        relation:='test_test',
        aggregate:='array_agg',
        expression:="address"
        )
    )
```

This shows me the correct values, but only in the preview of the expression and not in the attribute form or table when entering data.

Comment: the result of your expression is an array and therefore if the field is not correctly defined you will always get `NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Apparently this is not the only problem, however.

Comment: Can you share your sample data set and the project? This would make it much easier to test - otherwise, one has to rebuild the whole project/data...

Comment: Ok, edited the original again.

Comment: You are sure the field you are calculating is a Text field with sufficient length to hold the string?

Comment: @Matt: I tested it with different fields. By default I use a textfield with default length (shown as 0), but I tested a new field with length 500 (see above). It did not work in either case.

Comment: Forgive me, I am a little confused. You are creating a default value for the `address` field, which starts life empty? But you are using the expression "address" in your aggregate function, so where are the values supposed to come from?

Comment: The field is empty by default. When creating an entirely new feature which has no parent feature (e.g. a new house) the field is filled in manually. However, when creating a subfeature for this house (e.g. a room) the house is set as the parent feature. Then the data from the field "address" for the house should be copied automatically.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Sorry, to me, it's still confusing as I don't really understand what you intend to do - you speak about "buildings", "rooms" etc., but I don't see how these are connected to uuid, uuid_parent, addresses etc.

Comment: Also unclear: you say the expression "shows you the correct values, but not in the attribute form or table when entering data"... so when entering data, you override the default value, defined by the expression. So I'm really stuck and don't see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I just look for a way to automatically copy attribute entries from another feature on the same layer, which is linked by a recursive 1:n-relation. Buildings, rooms etc. were just to illustrate the problem. As described: With the code above, I get the correct result in the preview, but not when actually working with the data. It just shows NULL.

Answer (score 4):

As @pigreco mentioned, the result of your expression is an array. To convert it to either a text or a number, you have different options ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-functions)):

- To convert the array to a text (string), enclose your expression in an `array_to_string( )` function.
- To get the the **first** element of the array, use `array_first ()` - or `array_last ()` for the last one.
- To get any element of the array, use `array_get ( )[x]` and replace `x` with the index of the element you want to get (0 for the first one).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried all three variants, but I the result did not change. Two things appear as problems to me: 1) when entering data into the field "address" it jumps back to NULL, so I have to enter the data at least twice. 2) No matter what I enter as a parent feature, the field "address" remains NULL.

Comment: You must provide more information. Can you provide sample data and show us how your attribute table looks like? Have you defined field-type and length correctly?

Comment: I edited the original question. I hope that clarifies the question.